# Get all dates of a Year based on Day Name

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to take **all Dates of an year based on Day Name**. For example If I pass `Thu/Thursday and 2020 (Year)`. I need to `get all the Dates which are coming under Thursday on 2020`. **I might sent one or more Day names** For example I might sent `Thursday, Friday`. I couldn't find any answer to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a recursive CTE to generate all the dates and then filter the ones you want:

```
with dates as (
      select datefromparts(2020, 1, 1) as dte
      union all
      select dateadd(day, 1, dte)
      from dates
      where dte < datefromparts(2020, 12, 31)
     )
select d.*
from dates d
where datename(weekday, dte) = 'Thursday'
option (maxrecursion 0);
```